# How to count records after joining multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to count the numbers of records in schedule, order and store according to ecode from employee table using inner join. When I was using TestQuery the query counts perfectly but when I merge the query using inner join in MainQuery1 I got wrong result (from the result below). I found that the 3 result from test query doesn't match each other and doesn't accepts 0. Please help me to this. Thanks in advance.

I need to get the result like this:

```
     ecode    schedulecount noordercount    salescount
      BUL-SJU-01    135        7              135
      BUL-PLA-05    1          0              0
      BUL-PLA-03    121        0              120
      BUL-MAL-03    128        3              128
      BUL-CAL-01    48         10             46
      BUL-BOC-01    111        11             111
```

MainQuery1: This is my problem

```
SELECT 
    emp.[ecode],
    COUNT(sch.[user_id]) as schedulecount,
    COUNT(ord.[ecode]) as noordercount,
    COUNT(sto.[ecode]) as salescount
FROM [mydb].[dbo].[employee] as emp
INNER JOIN [mydb].[dbo].[schedule] as sch ON sch.[user_id] = emp.[ecode]
INNER JOIN [mydb].[dbo].[order] as ord ON ord.[ecode] = emp.[ecode]
INNER JOIN [mydb].[dbo].[store] as sto ON sto.[ecode] = emp.[ecode]
GROUP BY emp.[ecode]
ORDER BY emp.[ecode] DESC;
```

Wrong Result:

```
      ecode   schedulecount noordercount    salescount
      BUL-SJU-01    127575     127575    127575
      BUL-MAL-03    49152      49152     49152
      BUL-CAL-01    22080      22080     22080
      BUL-BOC-01    135531     135531    135531
```

TestQuery1:

```
SELECT 
    emp.[ecode],
    COUNT(sch.[user_id]) as schedulecount
FROM [mydb].[dbo].[employee] as emp
INNER JOIN [mydb].[dbo].[schedule] as sch ON sch.[user_id] = emp.[ecode]
GROUP BY emp.[ecode]
ORDER BY emp.[ecode] DESC;
```

Result:

```
     ecode           schedulecount
     BUL-SJU-01       135
     BUL-PLA-05       1
     BUL-PLA-03       121
     BUL-MAL-03       128
     BUL-CAL-01       48
     BUL-BOC-01       111
```

TestQuery2:

```
SELECT 
    emp.[ecode],
COUNT(ord.[ecode]) as schedulecount
FROM [mydb].[dbo].[employee] as emp
INNER JOIN [mydb].[dbo].[order] as ord ON  ord.[ecode] = emp.[ecode]
GROUP BY emp.[ecode]
ORDER BY emp.[ecode] DESC;
```

Result:

```
    ecode     schedulecount
    BUL-SJU-01      7
    BUL-MAL-03      3
    BUL-CAL-01      10
    BUL-BOC-01      11
```

TestQuery3:

```
SELECT 
    emp.[ecode],
    COUNT(sto.[ecode]) as salescount
FROM [mydb].[dbo].[employee] as emp
INNER JOIN [Z_ALI].[dbo].[M_STORE] as sto ON sto.[ecode] = emp.[ecode]
GROUP BY emp.[ecode]
ORDER BY emp.[ecode] DESC;
```

Result:

```
       ecode    salescount
       BUL-SJU-01   135
       BUL-PLA-03   120
       BUL-MAL-03   128
       BUL-CAL-01   46
       BUL-BOC-01   111
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach is to use `APPLY` in the `FROM` to get the counts:

```
USE mydb;


SELECT emp.ecode,
       Sc.schedulecount,
       O.noordercount,
       St.salescount
FROM dbo.employee emp
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS schedulecount
                  FROM dbo.schedule sch
                  WHERE sch.user_id = emp.ecode) Sc
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS noordercount
                  FROM dbo.[order] ord --Generally it's a good idea to avoid Reserved Keywords for Object names
                  WHERE ord.ecode = emp.ecode) O
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS salescount
                  FROM dbo.store sto
                  WHERE sto.ecode = emp.ecode) St
ORDER BY emp.ecode DESC;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1f48481ef042423ab0bd554c7f6bf9b3) showing results are correct per question.

*Crystal ball*:

```
SELECT emp.ecode,
       Sc.schedulecount,
       O.noordercount,
       St.salescount
FROM dbo.employee emp
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS schedulecount
                  FROM dbo.schedule sch
                  WHERE sch.user_id = emp.ecode) Sc
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS noordercount
                  FROM dbo.[order] ord --Generally it's a good idea to avoid Reserved Keywords for Object names
                  WHERE ord.ecode = emp.ecode) O
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS salescount
                  FROM dbo.store sto
                  WHERE sto.ecode = emp.ecode) St
WHERE Sc.schedulecount > 0  
   OR O.noordercount > 0
   OR St.salescount > 0
ORDER BY emp.ecode DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are counting along multiple dimensions.  There are multiple approaches to fixing this.  The simplest modification is to replace the `count()` with `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT emp.[ecode],
       COUNT(DISTINCT sch.<primary key>) as schedulecount,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ord.<primary key>) as noordercount,
       COUNT(DISTINCT sto.<primary key>) as salescount
FROM . . .
```

The column being counted is the primary key from each of the tables.

However, this is not optimal (generally) from a performance perspective.  You also lose `ecode`s that are missing *any* of the values (because you are using inner joins).

I think I would recommend correlated subqueries for this:

```
SELECT e.ecode,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM mydb..schedule s 
        WHERE s.user_id = e.ecode
       ) as schedulecount,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM mydb..order o 
        WHERE o.user_id = e.ecode
       ) as noordercount,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM mydb..store s 
        WHERE s.user_id = e.ecode
       ) as salescount
FROM [mydb].[dbo].[employee] e
ORDER BY e.[ecode] DESC;
```

Comment: @kirbyhipona . . . I caught that in the first query.  You are counting the `ecode` rather than the primary key.  I already changed the answer, but your question doesn't specify the name of the primary key.

Comment: I would ensure you declare the schema, rather than using `..` here though. Relying on the user's default schema *can* be a performance hit (as it has to be obtained), but also can give unexpected results if it isn't `dbo`.

Comment: Why wouldn't it, @kirbyhipona, you aren't filtering the results in your query, so every employee is going to be returned.

Comment: yes i filtered it but it return wrong result just like the WrongResults above